# Can't install Local Development Server

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

When I run the command `sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server` I get this

```
Polling for new version(s) to become available on npm... done
Successfully validated digital signature for @salesforce/lwc-dev-server.
Finished digital signature check.
Installing plugin @salesforce/lwc-dev-server@latest... failed
 »   Warning: @salesforce/lwc-dev-server > @oclif/config@1.18.17: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
    Error: C:\Users\Desk\AppData\Local\sf\client\2.29.5-06cd97f\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js add @salesforce/lwc-dev-server@latest --non-interactive --mutex=file:C:\Users\Desk\AppData\Local\sf\yarn.lock
    --preferred-cache-folder=C:\Users\Desk\AppData\Local\sf\yarn --check-files exited with code 1
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2h finally was able to install this plugin. My steps:

- node update from version 16 to version 18
- removed sf folder content based on your path
  (C:\Users\Desk\AppData\Local\sf...)
- run npm install -g node-gyp
- run npm install @oclif/core@latest
- run sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server